# the probability of a negative drift random walk never be positive

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

Suppose there is a random walk $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k,n\geq1$ and $S_0=0$, where $X_k$ are i.i.d. random variables.
 In addition, $-\infty< EX_1<0$ and $0<EX^2_1<+\infty$.

Define the maximum over all $S_n$ as $M:=\sup_{n\geq 0}\{S_n\}$.

It is intuitive that $M$ is almost surely $<+\infty$ and it can be verified by the Law of Large Numbers (see [Bounds on random walk with a negative drift](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51228/bounds-on-random-walk-with-a-negative-drift) and *Stopped random walks(2nd edition)* by Allan Gut Theorem 10.1 in Chapter 2).

In order to derive $E(M)$ with the help of laddder variables, it is crucial to obtain the probablity that $M=0$, i.e., $S_n$ never exceeds $0$.

My question is how to obtain $P(M=0)$? It has been shown that this probability is greater than $0$ in Lemma 11.3 of Chapter 2 in *Stopped random walks* by Allan Gut.

Comment: you wrote that your question is "how to obtain P(M=0)" but this is apparently much harder than the question stated in your title which maps to "how to obtain $P(M\geq 0)$" or even $P(M\gt 0)$.  You're going to have to deal with overshoots in some form for the title question and they are a huge problem for the your M=0 question.  For the title question, consider truncating the problem and applying the Wald Equation.

Comment: To be clarify Wald Equation will do it when $E[X] = 0$.  For non-fair game, the idea I had in mind actually involves exponential tilting, which requires that $X$ has an MGF, which is quite a bit stronger than what was stated here (i.e. X merely is known to have a second moment)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As $M:=\sup_{n\geq 0}\{S_n\}$ includes $S_0=0$. $M$ is always $\geq 0$. Actually the question "$S_n$ never be positive" corresponds to the case $M=0$. But the title of question is indeed not considerate becasue there may exist $S_n=0$ in the case $M=0$.

Comment: Could you please explain more about how to carry out the exponetial tilting with MGF existing? Becasue the assumption that MGF exists could be added if necessary.

Comment: Got it. I am having problems reading your postings for whatever reason.  Exponential tilting, well the basic idea, is here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496390/exponential-martingale-intuition/3496650 -- there's a collection of techniques related to using the MGF or its log (the cumulant).  I don't know of any nice results unless you are dealing with especially *simple* $X_i$.  As far as non-martingale methods go, Feller vol 2 is probably the standard reference (extensive ladder variables in chapter XII then much later fourier methods).  I'd anticipate this to be messy.